# How can I do operations among rows in a tibble?

Tags: r, function, tidyverse, tibble

I have a tibble which has stored variables taken at different points in the sea and at different depths, but I need to condense all the depths of the same point into a single row following a specific formula (the summation of the sum of values X and X+1 times the subtraction of the depth of X+1 minus depth of X and so on...), which I have wrote on excel as a way of better explaining what I'm trying to do

[image]

And here is an small sample of the (edited) data I'm working with

```
        long   lat station depth   no3
       <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
     1 -71.1   -32         1     0  9 
     2 -71.1   -32         1     5 14   
     3 -71.1   -32         1    10 10 
     4 -71.1   -32         1    20 11 
     5 -71.6   -32         2     0 13 
     6 -71.6   -32         2     5  8   
     7 -71.6   -32         2    10  2 
     8 -71.6   -32         2    20  6 
     9 -71.6   -32         2    50  4
    10 -71.6   -32         2    75  9
    # ... with 942 more rows
```

From what I read here in similar questions, I could use `aggregate` or `merge` but those only do the summation, and I don't know how to get it to do the entire equation. I'll appreciate any suggestion, I'm new to R and if I haven't been very clear (or the solution is actually quite simple) I'm sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `lead` function to create the sums based on the following row's data (use `lag` for the previous row), and then `sum` this new column in a `summarize`:

```
df <- data.frame(
  depth = c(0, 5, 10, 20, 50),
  NO3 = c(3, 5, 6, 2, 3)) %>%
  mutate(a = (lead(NO3) + NO3)*(lead(depth) - depth))

df

  depth NO3   a
1     0   3  40
2     5   5  55
3    10   6  80
4    20   2 150
5    50   3  NA

df %>%
  summarize(b = sum(a, na.rm = TRUE))

    b
1 325
```

Note that the `na.rm` in the sum is key here since the `lead` functions create `NA` values in the final row. These can be filled using the `default` argument.

**EDIT:**

If you'd like to apply this to more than just one column, you can use the "scoped" variants of `mutate` and `summarize`, by adding `_at` or `_if` to the end of these functions.

```
df2 <- data.frame(
  depth = c(0, 5, 10, 20, 50),
  NO3 = c(3, 5, 6, 2, 3),
  NO4 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
  NO5 = c(5, 4, 3, 2, 1))
```

`_at` functions require either a names vector or an index vector to determine which columns to operate on. All three of these will return the same thing, where `.x` refers to the column being modified:

```
df2 %>%
  mutate_at(c("NO3", "NO4", "NO5"), ~(lead(.x) + .x)*(lead(depth)-depth)) %>%
  summarize_at(c("NO3", "NO4", "NO5"), sum, na.rm = T)

df2 %>%
  mutate_at(vars(NO3:NO5), ~(lead(.x) + .x)*(lead(depth)-depth)) %>%
  summarize_at(vars(NO3:NO5), sum, na.rm = T)

df2 %>%
  mutate_at(2:4, ~(lead(.x) + .x)*(lead(depth)-depth)) %>%
  summarize_at(2:4, sum, na.rm = T)

  NO3 NO4 NO5
1 325 380 220
```

`_if` functions need a "predicate function" that determines whether a column will be operated on. Either of these, which check the name of the column, would work:

```
df2 %>%
  mutate_if(str_detect(colnames(.), "NO"), ~(lead(.x) + .x)*(lead(depth)-depth)) %>%
  summarize_if(str_detect(colnames(.), "NO"), sum, na.rm = T)

df2 %>%
  mutate_if(!str_detect(colnames(.), "depth"), ~(lead(.x) + .x)*(lead(depth)-depth)) %>%
  summarize_if(!str_detect(colnames(.), "depth"), sum, na.rm = T)

  NO3 NO4 NO5
1 325 380 220
```

Comment: THANKS! it worked!, just another question, how could I make it to apply this to many variables, but still using just the depth for the second part of the function?